# Junit Mockito -Mockito.spy() throwing securityexception

Tags: java, junit, mockito

Can someone please help to get rid of this issue.

I have project which will create the signed jar through pom.xml configuration.Now I added the dependency for Junit & mockito by adding below dependencies

If I am running my junit test cases through eclipse then its working fine but when I am building my project(maven-build-install) it is giving me security exception stating "class signer information does not match signer information of other classes in the same package"

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
<artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
<version>1.9.5</version>
<scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>junit</groupId>
<artifactId>junit</artifactId>
<version>4.11</version>
<scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

I know this type of error comes when you download the classes from two different jar but here I am not getting the point by just adding the Junit jar it is giving me the error.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5587656/verifying-jar-signature

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Verifying Jar Signature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5587656/verifying-jar-signature)
This link is helpful for me.

Basically when you have one signed jar in one project then you have to make sure other jar also will be signed.